# Azure artifact feed show only pom file even if jar packaging

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I have this dependency in my pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
        <artifactId>fake-sftp-server-rule</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

it uses sshd-core dependency this way

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sshd</groupId>
        <artifactId>sshd-core</artifactId>
        <version>[1,2)</version>
    </dependency>
```

I configured settings.xml correctly to get dependencies through azure artifact feed and it works because it gets other dependencies with no problem.

but for org.apache.sshd.sshd-core it gives me this error

```
Could not find artifact org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:jar:1.7.0
```

[image]

In azure artifact feed the dependency org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:jar:1.7.0 exists, but only the pom file is showing up, not the jar file 
[image]

What's the problem ? how to tell azure artifact to redownload the dependency correctely ? 
In maven central the dependency exist with jars files 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/sshd/sshd-core/1.7.0/

Comment: Did you try out below answer, Any update?

Answer (score 0):

It seems redownload sshd core to azure feed is unachieveable. The easiest way to fix the build failed error is to delete sshd-core package from your azure feed. So that maven will install this package from Maven Centrol everytime. But this method has a downside that sshd-core will never be repushed to your azure feed because of [immutability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/artifacts-key-concepts?view=azure-devops#recycle-bin). 
[image]

Another more complicated way to fix this is to delete your azure feed and recreate another one. You need to reconfig your pom file in this way. And all the dependencies will be downloaded again to the new azure feed. [check [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/5880) to permanently delete a feed using [restful api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/feed%20%20management/delete%20feed?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), if you need to receate a new azure feed using the same name but failed to do so].

**Addition:**

Maven central is set to the upstream resources by default. You can click on the gear icon on the right top corner and click upstream resources to manage the upstream resources.

[image]

Comment: for the first solution I need to change the settings.xml in to add maven repo, this don't fit my need,
the second solution also because we have internal packages in the feed, so we can't just delete the feed

Comment: You didnot need to change the settings.xml to add maven repo. The maven central repo is the upstream resources by default. You can find it in the `upstream resources` under `feed settings`